# NodeJS - Get record from SQL Server and pass to a Webservice

Tags: sql-server, node.js, web-services, stream

What's best algorithm for this issue using by **nodejs**:

1. get **N million** records (*streaming*) from a SQL Server database
2. after getting a record, pass that to a web service
3. get result from web service and update that a record

I don't want to keep all records in server's memory

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest here to take a look at the stream api from nodejs

https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html

Some possible (untested) example code here where pipe is used to get the data, make the request to the web service and perform an update.

```
let MssqlReadableStream = new MssqlClient({objectMode: true}).getRecords();
let HttpRequestServiceStream = new HttpRequestServiceStream({objectMode: true});
let MssqlWritableStream = new MssqlClient({objectMode: true}).updateRecord;


MssqlReadableStream
    .pipe(HttpRequestServiceStream)
    .pipe(MssqlWritableStream);
```

Comment: no, this isn't my answer. I want a solution and algorithm.